# Fundamental theorem of calculus and inverse functions

Tags: calculus

> Given that $f$ is a continuous and increasing function on $[a, b]$,
>   $c = f(a), d = f(b)$ and $a, b, c ,d \geq 0$, explain why
>
> $$\int_c^d f^{-1}(t)~dt = bd - ac - \int_a^b f(x)~dx$$

I am not sure how to treat the inverse function or the functions as the limits of integration. I tried to apply what I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits), but couldn't seem to create the RHS exactly.

$$\int_c^d f^{-1}(t)~dt = F^{-1}(d) - F^{-1}(c)$$
$$= F^{-1}(f(b)) - F^{-1}(f(a))$$
$$ = b - a$$

I am trying to understand exactly what the equality is trying to demonstrate in terms of properties of integrals rather than copying a formula from wikipedia superficially.

**EDIT:**

So, from the RHS, I would be taking the area of $ab$ (largest rectangle) and subtracting $ca$ (shaded rectangle) and then subtracting the area under $f(t)$ (lightly shaded)?

[image]

So I'm finding the area between $f^{-1}$ and the vertical axis from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$.

Comment: Try drawing a picture, just to get a feeling for why this is true.

Comment: I'm having difficulty drawing it since the functions are abstract. Would it be the area under some increasing inverse function and between two other functions all on the positive $x$ axis? Wouldn't that involve finding the points of intersection and splitting things into 3 integrals?

Comment: Draw a rectangle, with the x-axis going from a to b, and the y-axis going from c to d. Draw an increasing wiggly line from (a,c) to (b,d). This is $f$. What is $f^{-1}$ on this picture? What are the areas in question?

Comment: @Ananda: Thanks, momentary mind-blip. I have removed my comment.

Comment: This seems more like an application of Fubini to me.

Comment: The problem seems to stem from the convention of always graphing functions with the independent variable along the horizontal axis and the function values along the vertical axis. If you draw the picture using the usual convention for $f$, but the opposite convention for $f^{-1}$, then the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ will be the same! And the integral of $f^{-1}$ will be an area between that graph and the vertical axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a formal proof, start by substituting $t=f(x)$ in $\int_c^d f^{-1}(t)\,dt$.

For a pictorial proof:

[image: Pictorial proof]